# ¿como enviar un dato de un recyclerView a un Activity? ¿y Como devolver este dato al recyclerView si es modificado en el activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

hola soy nuevo en android, y no he podido aun dar solución a un inconveniente que tengo. Codifique un recyclrerViewAdapter que me permite mostrar una lista de productos en pantalla. Quiero resaltar que esta lista de items tiene las opciones de agregar productos o quitarlos.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Productos> items;

    String cantidadProductos;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Productos> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.img_item.setImageResource(items.get(position).getImagen());

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        holder.cardView.setTag(holder);

        holder.setOnclickListener();

    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            RecyclerViewHolder sh = (RecyclerViewHolder) view.getTag();
            int posicion = sh.getAdapterPosition();

            cantidadProductos = Integer.toString(sh.cont);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DialogoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imagen", items.get(posicion).getImagen());
            intent.putExtra("nombre", items.get(posicion).getNombre());
            intent.putExtra("precio", items.get(posicion).getPrecio());
            intent.putExtra("cantidadProductos", cantidadProductos);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

y en pantalla se ve algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este seria el RecyclerViewHolder donde implemente los metodos que permiten agregar o disminuir los productos:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


    ImageView img_item;
    ImageButton btn_add, btn_remove;
    TextView cantidad_producto;
    CardView cardView;

    int cont = 0;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        img_item = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_items);
        btn_add = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_agregar);
        btn_remove = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remover);
        cantidad_producto = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cantidad_agregada);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.onClickItems);
    }

    public void setOnclickListener(){
        btn_remove.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_agregar){
            cont++;

        }else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_remover && cont > 0){
            cont--;
        }else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_remover && cont == 0){
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"No puede eliminar los productos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        cantidad_producto.setText(Integer.toString(cont));
    }
}
```

al dar click sobre uno de los items de productos que se muestran en la imagen anterior, se abre un activity que funciona como un dialogo, y este recibe y muestra al usuario mas detalle de los productos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver, este dialogo permite modificar también la cantidad de productos que se pueden agregar. ya se logra enviar el dato de la cantidad desde el item al dialogo, pero no se como reenviar nuevamente este dato desde el activity hasta el items que esta en el recyclerVewAdapter.

este seria el código del activity:

```
public class DialogoActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView imagen;
    TextView nombre, precio, cantidadProductos;
    ImageButton btn_remove, btn_add;

    int cont;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialogo);

        imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_dialog);
        nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo_dialog);
        precio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.precio_dialog);
        cantidadProductos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_cantidad);
        btn_add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_agregar);
        btn_remove = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_remover);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int imagenProducto = intent.getExtras().getInt("imagen");
        String nombreProducto = intent.getExtras().getString("nombre");
        String precioProducto = intent.getExtras().getString("precio");
        String cantidad = intent.getExtras().getString("cantidadProductos");

        cont = Integer.parseInt(cantidad);

        imagen.setImageResource(imagenProducto);
        nombre.setText(nombreProducto);
        precio.setText(precioProducto);
        cantidadProductos.setText(cantidad);

        setOnClickListener();

    }

    public void setOnClickListener(){
        btn_remove.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_dialog_agregar){
            cont++;

        }else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_dialog_remover && cont > 0){
            cont--;
        }else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_dialog_remover && cont == 0){
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"No puede eliminar los productos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        cantidadProductos.setText(Integer.toString(cont));
    }
}
```

Agradezco la ayuda que me ofrezcan...

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿como enviar un dato de un recyclerView a un Activity?

### **1. RecyclerViewAdapter**

Necesitas sustituir esta línea:

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Por esta otra:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1); //el 1 es un id de requestcode
```

Para hacer que el diálogo devuelva datos.

---

### **2. DialogoActivity**

Ahora necesitas recoger los datos que deseas enviar de vuelta al RecyclerView. Imagino que tu diálogo lo cierras al presionar el botón `back`, así que deberías recogerlo ahí:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     super.onBackPressed();
     Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
     returnIntent.putExtra("result",cantidadProductos.getText()); //añadimos al intent de retorno el valor que deseas retornar
     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
     finish(); 
}
```

---

### **3. MainActivity** (o como hayas llamado a tu actividad que contiene el recyclerview)

Por último, necesitarás recuperar el dato en la Activity original, para eso necesitas reescribir el método:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) { //aqui comprobando el requestcode = 1 antes mencionado
      if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
          String resultadoDevuelto=data.getStringExtra("result"); //recupera tu dato proveniente del dialog
      }
  }
}//onActivityResult
```

> ¿y Como devolver este dato al recyclerView si es modificado en el
>   activity?

La variable `resultadoDevuelto` que puse justo en el código anterior contiene tu número modificado proveniente del dialog. Lo tienes en tu MainActivity y te quedaría añadirlo en la recyclerview utilizando tu **adaptador del recyclerview**, creando un nuevo método como por ejemplo `adaptador.setItemCantidad(resultado)` en tu adaptador.

Una cosa más, posiblemente necesites **enviar en todo el proceso cual es la posición del item** a modificar en el recyclerview, es decir, si es la primera hamburguesa, la segunda, la tercera, etc. Luego lo pasas también en `adaptador.setItemCantidad(resultado, posicion)` y ya puedes modificar la hamburguesa correcta con la cantidad correcta!

---

**Enlaces de interés:**

1. [Obtener el resultado de una actividad](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=es-419)
2. [Devolver un intent con resultado al presionar el botón Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794875/can-onbackpressed-set-and-return-an-intent-result)

Comment: Al iniciar el primer paso que me propones en el punto **1.RecyclerViewAdapter**. cuando sustituyo la linea me aparece como una linea de código invalida, y me muestra este mensaje: Cannot resolve method 'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)'

Comment: Si puedes iniciar context.startActivity(intent); puedes iniciar también este otro porque se usa de la misma forma. Estas usando el context???  context.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

Comment: eso es lo extraño, también lo utilizo con el  context.startActivityForResult(intent, 1); y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: Ok, el problema es que startActivityForResult(intent, 1) se debe llamar desde tu actividad la cual va a recibir el resultado en su método onActivityResult. Por tanto, el context aquí no te sirve. Puedes pasarle la actividad por parametro:

 public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Productos> items, Activity actividad)  y en tu actividad cuando crees la recyclerview se la pasas usando "this"

Comment: si en cambio ya le estas pasando el "this" al crear la recyclerview, haz un casting a Activity del contexto y deberias poder usar este metodo.